# C Client : recv not functioning as expected

Tags: c, networking, client, recv

This version of my mainloop function correctly, but as soon as change:

`char buff[MAX_BODY_LENGTH * 2]`
to  `char *buff = malloc(MAX_BODY_LENGTH * 2)`
the first recv does work anymore , it make buff null and don't wait for the first message from the server anymore.Yet it shouldn't have change anything, is it not the same type at the end ?

```c
int mainloop(int sockfd)
{
    char buff[MAX_BODY_LENGTH * 2];
    char *buff_brk;
    int numbytes;

    memset(&buff, 0,sizeof(buff));
    for (int command_valid = 1; 1 ; command_valid = 0) {
        recv(sockfd, buff, sizeof(buff), 0);
        //act_command(strdup(buff));
        printf("%s\n", buff);
        memset(&buff, 0,sizeof(buff));
        numbytes = read(0, buff, MAX_BODY_LENGTH * 2);
        buff[numbytes - 1] = '\0';
        send(sockfd, buff, sizeof(buff), 0);
        memset(&buff, 0,sizeof(buff));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `recv()` returns an `int`. `int` cannot be null. Your question doesn't make sense. Possibly you are confused by the fact that `sizeof(buff)` will become the size of a pointer if you change `buff` to a pointer? And why you would use `malloc()` when you could use an array on the stack is a mystery. But it is impossible to write correct networking code without storing the result of `recv()` into a variable and then (1) testing it for -1, (2) testing it for zero, and then (3) using it as the count of bytes received if the prior two tests failed. Don't write code like this.

Comment: i was talking about the buffer not the return, my bad

Comment: The buffer can't be null either. It is a local variable declared on the stack whose value cannot possibly be null. It might appear to be empty, because of only containing (or starting with) a null *character*: \which isn't the same thing, and is very far from your original claim.

Answer (score 1):

The culprit of your problem is that, `sizeof(buff)` in the first (VLA) version is what you expect. BUT in the second (malloc) case it returns the size of a `char*`. So 4 or 8 bytes instead of `MAX_BODY_LENGTH*2`

Comment: nope i change every siezof() by MAX_BODY_LENGHT it does not change the behaviour

Comment: Please update the snippet then as well. Also checking the return values of recv, read, send would help. Plus the call to memset make pointer of pointer in the second case.